# "statistical hypothesis testing"

Tags: grammar

Can I put "do" in front of "statistical hypothesis testing"? Thanks.

To address the management of any high risk aspects of the proposed work, we will do statistical hypothesis testing to decide on a final set of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

"Do" may be technically acceptable, but it sounds very wrong to me (a quantitative social scientist). I recommend "use" in your example sentence, but "perform" and "carry out" are fine too.

Answer (score 0):

"Do" is perfectly fine here, though "perform" might feel better to some.

Comment: And 'carry out' to perhaps more.